# iOS 15 - "Keep..." button in provisional user notifications doesn't save the settings

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

When receiving provisional user notifications in iOS 15 the "Turn Off..." button works fine, but the "Keep..." button doesn't save the settings. "Deliver Immediately" option doesn't do anything and "Deliver in Scheduled Summary" hides the buttons, but they appear again in next notification.
I've noticed this behavior with several different apps, for example Reddit. Does anyone know anything about this? I have also submitted a bug to Apple but no response so far.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. With iOS 15.2, this issue has been fixed.

Comment: tank you , I try it

Comment: I see it in ios15.2 , issue had been fixed