# iOS 15 Provisional Authorization Keep Actions

Tags: ios, push-notification

The [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications) states:

> If the user presses the Keep button, the system prompts them to choose
> between prominent or quiet notifications.

Yet in current iOS 15.4, the Keep button gives you the options to `Deliver Immediately" or "Deliver in Scheduled Summary". Pressing the former, the notification settings defaults to being delivered quietly.

Am I right assuming that the documentation just wasn't updated for iOS 15? And that there is no way to use provisional authorization with the option to directly switch to prominent delivery without having the user manually adjust the delivery settings?

(This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078348/ios-15-keep-button-in-provisional-user-notifications-doesnt-save-the-set))

Comment: I would very much like to know if this is a feature or a bug. Provisional push is less attractive to use if this is the case.